# What should do for this Scenerio in-app billing

Tags: android, in-app-billing

I have an application and I am trying to understand in-app billing. I want to **do this** : If a user buys an item with in-app billing. user can use this item with same account in different device without paying again. So my scenerio is this:

Assume that I have a application and it has in-app billing V3 service. And then a user purchases an "Managed Product" item and the user has an another device then the user wants to install this purcashed item in other device **without paying again**. But I read here, people talk about this problem:

> BILLING_RESPONSE_RESULT_ITEM_ALREADY_OWNED

At this point I am thinking to consume this product as soon as it is purchased. with this code:

```
mHelper.consumeAsync(inventory.getPurchase(SKU_MY_ITEM), mConsumeFinishedListener);
```

if it right way. what will the user see after clicking buy button in another device.(is it possible free purchase)

Also I am not sure what will happen, if the user uninstall and install again my app. what will user see if click a buy button. (purchase again or free purchase or  a ERROR)

Can you give advice about in app-billing service for 1 account and many device and also about what will see a user if try to purchase in another device even everything goes right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From here http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/api.html :

> Managed In-app Products
>
> Managed in-app products are items that have their ownership
>   information tracked and managed by Google Play. When a user purchases
>   a managed in-app item, Google Play stores the purchase information for
>   each item on a per-user basis. This enables you to later query Google
>   Play at any time to restore the state of the items a specific user has
>   purchased. This information is persistent on the Google Play servers
>   even if the user uninstalls the application or if they change devices.

What you want to do is ( like in the example app ) query the inventory on successful setup of your in app service and consume any managed item thus granting access to it.

Comment: So can I think like this. for example if I a made my item like android sample TrivialDrive's PREMIUM item type and than after purchasing it. if I make a query the inventory in different device, will it returns me true?

Comment: Yes...again : This information is persistent on the Google Play servers even if the user uninstalls the application or if they change devices.